# Litespeed brokes my css

Tags: plugins

I changed color for a text, but the color is not updated, I did flush all, purge all, and the button still same. If I deactivated Litespeed the color was changed. Do you know why? It's looks like a new css is not updated...

Comment: Did you also try purging css?. if that doesn't help the only other thing I can come up with is cache busting, but that will require you to edit the enqueue actions.

Comment: I solved, the problem was from CDN